# Filtro multi-etiqueta para Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

Intento realizar un pequeño buscador multi-etiqueta para mi blog de *Blogger* con el fin de que los usuarios puedan buscar a partir de uno o varios conceptos, articulos relacionados.

El problema es que necesitaría mas campos de filtro y editar su estilo. Lo he intentado de todas formas, pero por ahora no he tenido éxito.

Encontré este ejemplo:

```js
function getValue() {
 var valcmbColumn = document.getElementById("cmbColumn").value;
 valcmbSidebar = document.getElementById("cmbSidebar").value;
 valcmbColor = document.getElementById("cmbColor").value;
 valcmbFeatures = document.getElementById("cmbFeatures").value;
 valOutput = (valcmbColumn + valcmbSidebar + valcmbColor + valcmbFeatures);
 window.open("/search/label/" + valOutput, "_self");
}
function toggle_visibility(id) {
 var e = document.getElementById(id);
 if(e.style.display == "block") {
  e.style.display = "none";
 } else {
  e.style.display = "block";
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-outer">
  <div class="tabs-cap-top cap-top">
    <div class="cap-left"></div>
    <div class="cap-right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fauxborder-left tabs-fauxborder-left">
    <div class="fauxborder-right tabs-fauxborder-right"></div>
    <div class="region-inner tabs-inner">
      <div class="tabs section" id="crosscol">
        <div class="widget HTML" id="HTML3">
          <h2 class="title">Multi Label Search</h2>
          <div class="widget-content">
            <div id="multi-search">
              <select id="cmbColumn" name="cmbColumn">
                <option value="" />Columns
                <option value="1%20Column+" />1 Column
                <option value="2%20Column+" />2 Column
                <option value="3%20Column+" />3 Column
                <option value="4%20Column+" />4 Column
              </select>
              <select id="cmbSidebar" name="cmbSidebar">
                <option value="" />Sidebars
                <option value="1%20Left%20Sidebar+" />1 Left Sidebar
                <option value="2%20Left%20Sidebar+" />2 Left Sidebar
                <option value="1%20Right%20Sidebar+" />1 Right Sidebar
                <option value="2%20Right%20Sidebar+" />2 Right Sidebar
                <option value="Left%20and%20Right+" />Left and Right
              </select>
              <select id="cmbColor" name="cmbColor">
                <option value="" />Colors
                <option value="Black+" />Black
                <option value="Blue+" />Blue
                <option value="Brown+" />Brown
                <option value="Green+" />Green
                <option value="Gray+" />Gray
                <option value="Orange+" />Orange
                <option value="Pink+" />Pink
                <option value="Red+" />Red
                <option value="Violet+" />Violet
                <option value="White+" />White
                <option value="Yellow+" />Yellow
              </select>
              <select id="cmbFeatures" name="cmbFeatures">
                <option value="" />Features
                <option value="Ads%20Ready" />Ads Ready
                <option value="Bookmark%20Ready" />Bookmark Ready
                <option value="Custom%20Navbar" />Custom Navbar
                <option value="Page%20Number" />Page Number
                <option value="Slideshow" />Slideshow
              </select>
              <input onclick=" getValue() " value="Filter" type="button" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
            <span class="widget-item-control">
            <span class="item-control blog-admin">
            <a class="quickedit" href="//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4472703516037708465&amp;widgetType=HTML&amp;widgetId=HTML3&amp;action=editWidget&amp;sectionId=crosscol" onclick=" return _WidgetManager._PopupConfig(document.getElementById(&quot;HTML3&quot;)); " target="configHTML3" title="Edit">
            <img alt="" src="http://img1.blogblog.com/img/icon18_wrench_allbkg.png" height="18" width="18" />
          </a>
        </span>
      </span>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class="tabs section" id="crosscol-overflow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-cap-bottom cap-bottom">
    <div class="cap-left"></div>
    <div class="cap-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

He conseguido añadir más opciones en cada desplegable, lo que me está resultando imposible es añadir más desplegables y editar su estilo.

Answer (score 0):

Hola bro quiza te pueda ayudar con esto y en caso logres el filtro no olvides compartirlo :)

Para llamar 2 etiquetas o muchas mas la url del sitio web debe ir asi:

[https://www.MIWEB.com/search/?q=+label=Acción+label=Película](https://www.MIWEB.com/search/?q=+label=Acci%C3%B3n+label=Pel%C3%ADcula)

Y de esa forma ir aumentando las etiquetas con un +label= y en caso la etiqueta lleve un espacio de por medio iria asi:

https://www.MIWEB.com/search/?q=+label="Artes Marciales"+label=Película

Tambien es posible poner doble ++ en el primer label, ya que si la url de la web no lleva el signo + no se muestra ninguna entrada pero si le pones un + se muestran todas las entradas,

https://www.MIWEB.com/search/?q=+   MUESTRA TODAS LAS ENTRADAS

https://www.MIWEB.com/search/?q=++label="Artes Marciales"+label=Película  MUESTRA TODAS LAS ENTRADAS CON ESAS 2 ETIQUETAS SELECIONADAS.

Lo que yo hice fue esto:

Por defecto el apartado donde ira el filtro llevara

https://www.MIWEB.com/search/?q=+

De esa forma me muestra todas las entradas.

Al elegir las 3 opciones de los desplegables o solo una opción, se acumularia asi:

+label="Artes Marciales"+label=Acción+label=Película

y al darle a filtrar lo agregaria delante de la url de la web que lleva por defecto osea :

https://www.MIWEB.com/search/?q=+

y quedaria asi :

https://www.MIWEB.com/search/?q=++label="Artes Marciales"+label=Acción+label=Película

Con 2 signos de ++ al principio del primer label que no causa ningun problema en la busqueda de las etiquetas.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour], esta es la zona de respuetas amigo por lo tanto tu duda aquí no va, recomendación: elimina esto, checa los enlaces que te di y abre una nueva pregunta